# Can I use offline UPS for a PC? Will the delay affect my PC if it is running when the power goes out?

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering, ups, electrical, pc

Can I use offline UPS for a PC? Will the delay affect my PC if it is running when the power goes out? im planning to set up an offline UPS at my home i need my PC running without any disruption but i was wondering whether i can run PC on an offline UPS without any interruption.Will the offline UPS delay from main supply to battery affect my pc when the power goes out?

Comment: This question is off topic - a *specific* challenge in *designing* a UPS could be on-topic, but applying an off-the-shelf one to off-the-shelf office equipment is not within the mission of this stack exchange site.

Comment: sorry im new to stack exchange.I thought it is platform where you could ask technical doubts too. so where do i ask if this site cant answer it or call it off topic? I've also asked this in other forums too but still havent received a clear answer.Why is stack exchange built in the first place if it calls something off topic since it dont deal with designing?

Comment: @firefly Its the users job write a good question. This is a forum for electrical design questions. Cross posting is generally discouraged across the internet don't do it. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If both the UPS and your power supply are commercial products carrying UL or CE or both there would be no problem. There are requirements for the power supply to continue working with full load for at least one half cycle (10ms for 50Hz) without mains. Also the requirements for the UPS say that it should start to supply power for less than one half cycle.

Comment: what is the result of set-point hysteresis in a brownout , is it synchronous? do all PC PSU's reject line transients the same?  They are most common because they are 25%cheaper. not better. So it depends on both UPS and PSU quality for reliability.

Comment: I am not goint to argue on this. All PSU's should be designed to withstand 10ms @ full load and all UPS shall fire up before 10ms. If the power supply is properly designed it will survuve this transient. This kind of UPS's are the most used in SOHO applications. Of course 'online' is the best, but this will do too, and that was the question.

Comment: but if Vin is 100V/us during transfer after a dropout will,PSU reject it?

Comment: This can't happen beacuse the relay of the line-interractive UPS connects its low frequency transformer whinding (couple of **dozens of mH**) to the PSU's capacitor - **hundreds of uF**.

Comment: That isn't much in terms of sqrt(LC). The question becomes how much energy remains before the 10ms transfer takes place and what is the ESR of all loads. This is critical to determine if there is adequate storage time while V is unstable.

Comment: If transfer time is 10ms and storage time is 10ms then the race can be forced to win or lose with other loads in parallel

Comment: Simply put, you cannot guarantee , firefly that any UPS will work every time. Whereas Online works all the time on the output.

Answer (score -1):

PC PSU's only store energy for 1 cycle minimum at full load. Thus if offline switcher causes. large dropout, it will fault some PC's.

This is why online UPS is best.

Offline UPS is just a life preserver for most but not all loads like Laser printers. Whereas Online UPS is a better "generator" with low Z and better load regulation.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-things-you-should-know-about-deploying-a-ups/

There are 3 types of UPS

1. Offline ... good
2. Offline interactive... better
3. Online , dual converters.... best

There are 5 types of DCDC converters used in UPS each with different cost, loss, surge  and impedance load regulation tradeoffs.

- Forward Converter
- Push-Pull Converter
- Half-Bridge Converter
- Full-Bridge Converter
- Flyback Converter ... cheapest

Comment: Most commonly used UPS for PC are exactly `line-interactive` or in other words `offilne`. See my answer below.

Comment: yes but depends PSU supply regulation , % load and transfer glitch, so I stand by my opinion from my experience. (-1) Todor

Comment: I read somewere that the delay in switching from main to battery is around 20-100ms .So when power goes out when im working on my PC will the delay cause my PC to shutdown? i know the online UPS are the bests but they cost much more than an offline.A single online UPS wont be enough for me since im planning to run a mining rig which will draw considerable amount of power a online UPS of that rating would expensive .We often have blackouts in the winter.

Comment: @firefly open a datasheet of *whatever* UPS and look for the parameter **transfer time**.