# ATX PSU and offline UPS compatibility

Tags: power-supply, ups, atx, regulations

Specifically how well can an ATX PSU and in turn the Computer it is powering cope with power loss for x miliseconds during the changeover from Grid AC to offline UPS inverter AC

[Can I use offline UPS for a PC? Will the delay affect my PC if it is running when the power goes out?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307711/can-i-use-offline-ups-for-a-pc-will-the-delay-affect-my-pc-if-it-is-running-whe)

is an interesting conversation on the subject and opinions are expressed about european regulations for ATX design specifying that it should cope with full load for half of a cycle or 10ms of power loss.

I have however been unable to find the regulations that state this as a requirement

really i am just looking for some concrete indication that ATX AND OR general purpose CE certified PSU's can cope with half cycle power loss

it is a bit easier to find out the UPS transfer time in ms as its usually well published

i am specifically interested in offline UPS compatibility and not concerned with other benifits of other UPS tolologies.

thanks in advance

please advidse if i need to repost this elsewhere.

Comment: does the UPS output actually drop?

Comment: It depends on the value of x

Comment: I can tell you that I use an APC Backup UPS 650 at work for my computer and I can confirm that the computer never loses power when the power goes out.

Comment: yes the fail over from grid AC to UPS AC with an offline UPS topology does disconnect supply from loads for a perios of time in ms.

Answer (score 4):

A low-cost offline UPS design is based on the fact that the load has sufficient capacitance to continue operating for a brief moment during a power interruption event, before the backup power is switched on.

### An experiment

For starter, I just did an experiment with my own offline UPS. Channel 2 (blue) is the AC input, channel 1 (orange) is the UPS output, both are 100x probes. The external trigger is a remote control signal.

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot]

As you see, AC power is interrupted at the center of the graph, immediately, the AC power starts returning to 0 V. The interruption is not instantaneous due to the capacitance of the load. After approximately 10 ms, the UPS's modified square wave backup power kicked in as expected (Ignore the glitches from the now disconnected Channel 2, they are common-mode noise from the UPS due to my measurement setup).

Then I measured the exact transfer time of my UPS.

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot, with cursor measuring the transfer time of an offline UPS.]

It's approximately 7.8 ms for this single switch-over (it may vary depending on the specific location of the power interruption on the AC cycle). Because the transfer time is sufficiently fast, within half a cycle of the 50 Hz mains voltage, there is no interruption to the load on the UPS. The fact that my oscilloscope is still running is the proof.

### ATX specification

But the real question is: how fast is fast enough? Since most UPS units are designed to power personal computers, thus, they are usually designed to meet or exceeded the ATX specification.

In [Desktop Platform Form Factors Power Supply - Design Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/resellers-power-supply-design-guide-changes.pdf#page=20) (a.k.a. The "ATX" spec) by Intel, page 20 and 21, the required hold-up time after a power interruption is specified.

> **3.2.9 Voltage Hold-Up Time** - Required.
> The power supply should maintain output regulations per Table 3-2 despite a loss of input power at the low-end nominal range- 115 VAC / 47 Hz or 230 VAC / 47 Hz – at maximum continuous output load as applicable for a minimum of 17ms (T5+T6).
>
> [image: ATX power timing diagram]
> Parameter:
>
> - T5 - AC loss to PWR_OK hold-up time: > 16 ms
> - T6 - PWR_OK inactive to DC loss delay: > 1 ms

To rephrase it, when the AC line voltage is interrupted, the +12 V, +5 V, and +3.3 V output rails start to fall. For a properly designed, ATX-compliant power supply, the power supply should hold up for at least 16 ms before the `PWR_OK` (a.k.a the well-known Power Good) signal becomes `LOW`, telling the motherboard that it has failed. Furthermore, even after `PWR_OK` becomes `LOW`, it's also required that all output voltage rails continue to hold up for at least 1 milliseconds before they has fallen below the 95% threshold of their nominal output voltages.

Here's some actual oscilloscope screenshots showing the response of a consumer-grade 650 W ATX power supply after the loss of AC input under full load.

[image: Oscilloscope screenshot, Power-Good measured]

<sub>Source: [fcpowerup.com](https://www.fcpowerup.com/coolermaster-mwe-gold-v2-650w/#scroll-20),  fair use. *Note: this is a cool Chinese PC review website which conducts independent verification of consumer PSUs according to the full ATX specs.*</sub>

Using the ATX standard as the guideline, offline UPS units are designed to have a *transfer time* below 16 ms to ensure the proper operation of personal computers. For example, this is the specification of an offline UPS from APC.

[image: APC UPS specification]

<sub>Source: [APC Back-UPS™ Pro 700 User Manual](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_File_Name=BU%20UM%20990-3583C%20MN01%20EN.pdf#page=8), fair use.</sub>

Note that the specified maximum *transfer time* is 10 ms, well below the hold-up time for an ATX power supply.

Thus, given a UPS that works as advertised and a personal computer with a standard-compliant ATX power supply, an offline UPS is perfectly compatible with a PC. Anecdotally, I've personally used them for a decade without experiencing any problem during a switch-over.

However, non-compliant hardware (including both UPS and PSU units) can occasionally be found, and theoretically, an old power supply can become non-compliant as well due to the loss of capacitance in aged electrolytic capacitors.

Finally, although the manufacturers probably tested them on most consumer electronics with confidence. But ultimately there is no guarantee that an offline UPS will always work for all types of electronic devices and load types. This is why an "online" UPS with sine wave output is considered advantageous:

1. No switch-over transient or interruption. Transients from the power grid during normal operation is also greatly suppressed, possibly providing better surge protection.
2. Better compatibility with reactive loads.

However, when you're only intended to power devices with switched-mode power supplies like personal computers, which are known to almost always work, an offline UPS can be an inexpensive solution for preventing data loss.

Answer (score 3):

The requirement is in the ATX power supply specifications.

The supply is required to handle AC power loss of at least 16ms.

Comment: thank you for that, i should have thought to check it. Here is an extract from the standard.    ***       3.2.9Voltage Hold-U p Time -  RequiredThe power supply should maintain output regulations per Table 3-2 despite a loss of input power at the low-end nominal range-115 VAC / 47 Hz or 230 VAC / 47 Hz – at maximum continuous output load as applicable for a minimum of 17ms (T5+T6).           https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/power-supply-design-guide-june.pdf   page 20